# JMockit - Unexpected invocation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I have a simple implementation using JMockit for unit test. The implementations are as following

`Team` class

```
public class Team {
    private TeamLeader teamLeader;
    public Team(TeamLeader teamleader) {
        this.teamLeader = teamleader;
    }

    public boolean hasDiscussion() {
        System.out.println("Discussion is hold by " + teamLeader.getName());
        Discussion discussion = new Discussion();
        return discussion.start();
    }
}
```

`TeamLeader` class

```
public class TeamLeader {

    private String name;

    public TeamLeader(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

`Discussion` class

```
public class Discussion {

    public boolean start() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, I have a unit test to test function `hasDiscussion` as following

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class TeamTest {

    private Team team;

    @Test
    public void hasDiscussion(@Mocked TeamLeader teamLeader, @Mocked Discussion discussion) {

        new Expectations() {{
            teamLeader.getName(); result = "teamleader";
            discussion.start(); result = true;
        }};

        team = new Team(teamLeader);
        boolean actualResult = team.hasDiscussion();

        new Verifications() {{
            assertThat(actualResult, is(true));
        }};

    }
}
```

When executing the test, I got the following error

```
Unexpected invocation of:
entity.Discussion#Discussion()
   on instance: entity.Discussion@7b70deb2
when was expecting an invocation of:
entity.Discussion#start()
   on mock instance: entity.Discussion@6f93ad02
mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Unexpected invocation of:
entity.Discussion#Discussion()
   on instance: entity.Discussion@7b70deb2
when was expecting an invocation of:
```

Any ideas for this sort of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because your `hasDiscussion` method was creating a new instance of `Discussion` class, and in this case, you can’t mock it.
To solve this you can receive the `Discuss` class as a parameter of the method and send the mock, our inject the Discuss class in `Team` class constructor.